# Can I predict percentage change in earnings from percentage change in produced and percentage changed in price?

Tags: regression

I have computed percentage change from time1 to time2 for several variables.

Can I predict percentage change in earnings from percentage change in produced and percentage changed in price?

When I ran a model with actual data and dummy coded time (time1=1, time2=0), the dummy variable was not statistically significant. But there are large changes.

Comment: Could you please make your question a little more understandable?

Comment: Or for example mention what stat package you are using ? (R, SAS, SPSS, etx ?)

Comment: Overhauled title and question text to stop it coming up in list of related questions as the old title "linear regression"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but I think that using percentages in a regression framework is likely to lead to a model that has little value.  I would try to generalize the model so that the percentage change is a special case, but that more complex behaviour is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to have problems with covariance - your model fails to meet the assumption of linear regression that the observations are independent, because a subject in your study will be correlated with itself between time 1 and time 2 (By the way, what are your observations?  One for each product type?)

You might want to look into "repeated measures" methods.

Comment: Thank you- mbq and stoplan - I computed mean in time1 and time2, and percent change. There are several obs for each idno, but not an equal  no. of obs for each idno in each time period.  There are 2 or 3 vars that cause change in dep. var, but the means are diff from time1 to time2. I am not clear on repeated measures - in SAS I used proc mixed w/repeated option but I am not clear on results!

Comment: There is a specific change in 1 indep. var, X1 in time2. What I want to do is show statistically what is causing change in dep var from time1 to time2.  How much is due to change in X1? Am I still unclear?

Comment: @Tailltu I think, ideally, editing the question itself to lend clarity is preferable. That way your question would show up in searches by other people who may have an issue similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Regress the X1 value for time1 (and any other covariates you want) on the X1 variable for time 2 (your dependent variable).  Your regression model will look something like this:

"x1 time 2" = "x1 time1" + x2 + x3 + x4 etc.

Your regression coefficients for x2....xn will be the effect of changes of that variable on "x1 time2" controlling for "x1 time 1" (and everything else in the model).  Therefore you'll be able to see what is going on at time2 controlling for where things were at time 1.